# Tunnel of public IPv4 subnet to local server using Bird and WireGuard

Tags: networking, tunnel, wireguard

With [Bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bird_Internet_routing_daemon) 1.6.8, I successfully announced a IPv4 `/24` subnet, and I'm mostly using example IP addresses/subnets according to [RFC 5735](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735):

```
root@tunnel0:~# birdc show proto all vultr
BIRD 1.6.8 ready.
name     proto    table    state  since       info
vultr    BGP      master   up     2024-01-18  Established
```

I now want to use a part of it [`203.0.113.32/27` of `203.0.113.0/24`] on my local server at home using WireGuard

- The local server is the host for multiple KVM guests (`libvirt` on Debian 12 Bookworm).
- The host itself needs one public IPv4 address, as well as the guests.
- I want to use policy-based routing instead of NAT if possible.
- I do use `nftables` and not `iptables` as the latter is becoming more and more deprecated.

I was able to setup the WireGuard connection between both servers, but I don't know how to configure the public IPv4 subnet so that I can use that instead of the private subnet:

- **WireGuard Server:**

  ```ini
  [Interface]
  Address = 10.17.0.1/24
  SaveConfig = true
  ListenPort = 51820
  PrivateKey = ...

  [Peer]
  PublicKey = ...
  AllowedIPs = 10.17.0.0/24
  ```
- **WireGuard Client: (= local server/host for VMs)**

  ```ini
  # Client
  [Interface]
  PrivateKey = ...
  Address = 10.17.0.128/24

  # Server
  [Peer]
  PublicKey = ...
  AllowedIPs = 10.17.0.0/24
  PersistentKeepalive = 25
  Endpoint = 198.51.100.77:51820
  ```
- **Bird:**

  ```ini
  router id 198.51.100.77;

  protocol bgp vultr
  {
    # substitute with your AS or Vultr's private AS
    local as 123456;
    source address 198.51.100.77;
    import none;
    export all;
    graceful restart on;
    multihop 2;
    neighbor 169.254.169.254 as 64515;
    password "...";
  }

  protocol static
  {
    route 203.0.113.0/24 via 198.51.100.77;
  }

  protocol device
  {
    scan time 5;
  }
  ```

Comment: Please don't screenshot terminal output, instead please copy the output and place within a codebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On both hosts, disable wg-quick's automatic policy routing, by setting e.g. `Table = 2` in both configurations. (I would even use `Table = off` to disable its automatic route addition as well and do it all by hand, but I think in your case it's fine to keep it; it'll be useful later.)

   ```
   [Interface]
   Table = 2
   ```

   When the WireGuard tunnel is restarted, look at `ip rule` and `ip route show table 2` to see what the routing policy is. I'd expect *no* non-default rules (only the three shown below), and a single "dev wg0" route in table 2.

   ```
   Both# ip -4 rule
   0:      from all lookup local
   32766:  from all lookup main
   32767:  from all lookup default
   ```

   ```
   Both# ip -4 route show table 2
   10.17.0.0/24 dev wg0
   ```
2. Update the tunnel's AllowedIPs to match the traffic that will be going through it.

   - On the server side, packets with dst=203.0.113.32/27 will be sent to the client, and packets with src=203.0.113.32/27  will be received from the client, therefore the server-side [Peer] entry for the client must include 203.0.113.32/27 in the client's AllowedIPs.
   - On the client side, packets from *any* src (that is, from the entire Internet) will be received from the tunnel, and packets to *any* dst will be sent back to the tunnel, therefore the client-side configuration needs AllowedIPs to allow 0.0.0.0/0 i.e. everything.

   I would just set AllowedIPs to 0.0.0.0/0 on both sides, so that WireGuard becomes a completely standard tunnel that carries any IP traffic it's told.

   ```
   [Peer]
   AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
   ```

   Restart the tunnel; use `wg show` to make sure the changes are in effect.

   ```
   Both# wg show
   peer: asdf
       allowed ips: 0.0.0.0/0
   ```

   Also use `ip route show table 2` again, to check how wg-quick's translation of AllowedIPs to system routes was affected by this.

   ```
   Both# ip r sh table 2
   default dev wg0
   ```
3. On the server, actually route the addresses via the WireGuard wg0 interface.

   ```
   # ip route add 203.0.113.32/27 dev wg0
   ```

   Make it stick:

   ```
   [Interface]
   PostUp = ip route add 203.0.113.32/27 dev wg0
   ```

   - Because it's a Layer-3 tunnel interface, there's no need to specify a `via` gateway; all routes can be just `dev wg0` (although adding `via 10.17.0.128` is harmless, but also useless). WireGuard uses AllowedIPs to decide which peer to forward the packets to; a pure point-to-point tunnel like GRE would simply send everything to "the other end". However, if it were a Layer-2 tunnel like L2TP or ZeroTier, you would have to specify `via 10.17.0.128` as the gateway.
   - In this case, wg-quick has already added routes to table 2, so we *could* have just used that by adding an `ip rule` instead of the above route – and that will in fact be *necessary* on the client side – but on the server, start with a plain route for the sake of understanding.
   - Technically you can use Bird's 'protocol static' to make the route permanent instead of wg-quick's 'PostUp', but I'd suggest the latter for now, because with Bird you'd need to add filters to prevent the /27 route from being sent via BGP. (Your peer will not accept a /27 route anyway, but it's good practice to not advertise anything other than the /24 aggregate route.)
4. Use tcpdump to verify that packets go towards the client.

   - Run a `ping 203.0.113.32` on the Vultr server.
   - Run `tcpdump -n -i wg0` on the Vultr server to make sure those packets go out through the tunnel (i.e. the routing table is OK)
   - Run the same `tcpdump -n -i wg0` on the WG client to make sure the packets *arrive* at the other end of the tunnel (i.e. the AllowedIPs are OK).
   - At this point there won't be any ping replies yet – that's fine; get it working in one direction first.

   Also verify that packets *from the Internet* arrive at your VPS and are being forwarded to the client.

   - Run a `ping 203.0.113.32` (with the `-t` option if Windows) on some machine that is *not* the home server nor the VPS. (Use a public "Looking glass" site if you don't have any other location to ping from – many large carriers let you ping/traceroute stuff from their network.)
   - Run `tcpdump -n -i eth0 "host 203.0.113.32"` on the Vultr server to see if the packets arrive at the server (i.e. the BGP announcement is OK).
   - Run `tcpdump -n -i wg0` on the Vultr server to make sure those packets are being forwarded out through the tunnel. If they aren't, check iptables rules.
   - Again run it on the client to make sure packets arrive.
5. On the client, you're now receiving packets 'to' 203.0.113.32/27. For all intents and purposes, you can deal with that as if the client was directly doing the BGP announcement and as if the tunnel weren't there (except for policy routing still being needed to select between two uplinks).

   I'll be assuming your VM host has a single `vmbr0` bridge that all VMs connect to.

   I can't provide any instructions for libvirt networking, because I have only barely touched libvirt at all, but all that's necessary is configuring the libvirt network IP addresses – there wouldn't be anything WireGuard-specific or BGP-specific in that.
6. Assign one address to the host itself. Add it as a /32 to some other interface ('lo' is traditional, 'dummy0' or 'wg0' can be used too) so that it continues working even while vmbr0 is down for some reason.

   Let's use the 1st address of the /27:

   ```
   Client# ip addr add 203.0.113.33/32 dev lo
   ```

   (Because it's a /32, you could even use the 0th address i.e. `.32/32`; the "reserved" rule does not apply here. Likewise, a /32 has no broadcast so the last address `.63` is also usable.)

   At this point, if you still have that `ping` running, the host should begin sending out replies (although via the wrong interface still), so use tcpdump again to verify that there are both ICMP Echo Requests and Responses.

   ```
   Client# tcpdump -e -n -i any "net 203.0.113.32/27"
   ```
7. Add a policy routing rule that directs traffic via wg0 depending on the source address.

   ```
   Client# ip rule add from 203.0.113.32/27 lookup 2
   ```

   Normally you'd need to actually add the routes to table 2 first, but wg-quick has already done that (from the AllowedIPs). Still, you should verify that it's correct (and correct it if not):

   ```
   Client# ip -4 r ls table 2
   default dev wg0
   ```

   You can use `ip route get` to check what the kernel thinks about any specific packet:

   ```
   Client# ip route get 8.8.8.8
   8.8.8.8 via <LanGW> dev eth0 src <LanIP>

   Client# ip r get 8.8.8.8 from 203.0.113.33
   8.8.8.8 dev wg0 src 203.0.113.33 table 2
   ```
8. With the policy rule in place, tcpdump on the client host should now be showing that the Echo Reply packets indeed go through wg0 instead of eth0 – and **the `ping 203.0.113.32` should actually be receiving replies now**. If not, repeat tcpdump at every step (client wg0, server wg0, server eth0) to find where it gets stuck.
9. All that's left is to assign the rest of the /27 to your VM bridge like it's a normal subnet:

   ```
   Client# ip addr add 203.0.113.33/27 dev vmbr0
   ```

   ```
   VM_1# ip addr add 203.0.113.34/27 dev eth0
   ```

   ...and edit the libvirt network XML to actually make that persistent (and maybe even make it do DHCP for this network).

---

Other notes:

- > With Bird 1.6.8,

  You should be using [Bird 2](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=bird2) by now. While the 1.6.x series isn't going to just stop working, it *has* stopped receiving any further development (with only a single fix having been done since the 1.6.8 release four years ago).
- ```
  protocol bgp vultr {
    import none;
    export all;
  }
  ```

  You should have explicit filters for what you're exporting to eBGP peers (good practice *even if* the peer already filters what they import from you). For example:

  `export where net = 203.0.113.0/24;`
  `export where net ~ [ 203.0.113.0/24 ];`
  `export filter { if net ~ [ 203.0.113.0/24 ] then accept; reject; };`
- ```
  protocol static {
    route 203.0.113.0/24 via 198.51.100.77;
  }
  ```

  `route 203.0.113.0/24 unreachable` might be preferred. The gateway specification will not be part of the eBGP announcement, anyway (eBGP always advertises self as nexthop) – but it *will* be exported to a local kernel route, and it's a good idea to have an 'unreachable' route that covers all parts of your network that aren't specifically routed elsewhere.
- ```
  protocol device {
    scan time 5;
  }
  ```

  `scan time` has stopped being necessary many releases ago – Bird gets immediate Netlink notifications from the kernel. It's enough to have an empty `protocol device {}` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I will try that later. I just want to state, that in case the firewall is touched, that I use `nftables` instead of `iptables`, because the latter is becoming more and more deprecated. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which; both have the same capabilities, more-or-less the same general concepts. (Most importantly, both handle fwmarks/connmarks in the same general way even if it's [spelt differently](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Setting_packet_metainformation), although in this case you don't really need fwmarks just yet.) Read "check your iptables" as "do whatever is necessary to allow forwarded packets through your firewall".

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get packets from the internet (see 2nd test in chapter 4).`ip -4 r ls table 2` gives me `default dev wg0 scope link` on both sides. Is `scope link` the reason?

Comment: From the internet or from the VPS itself? Test first with running a `ping` on the VPS (as that only involves local routing but doesn't yet involve packet forwarding).

Comment: From the internet to the Vultr VPS (2nd test in chapter 4). I will receive the packets, but at the wrong interface: `eth0` instead of `wg0`. But I can see the route in `ip route` (`203.0.113.34/27 dev wg0 scope link`).

Comment: That sounds completely normal: eth0 is where your Internet connection is, so naturally it's the interface through which you will receive those packets from Vultr, and the server's own routes will only take effect _after_ the packets have been received. Is the global "IP forwarding" setting enabled on the server (`sysctl net.ipv4.conf.{all,eth0,wg0}.forwarding`)? Do your firewall rules (nftables 'hook forward') permit the packets to go through? Once forwarding works, the server should be seeing the packets on both eth0 (inbound) **and** wg0 (outbound).

Comment: I uncommented `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and then did `sysctl -p`, now I can see the packets also on `wg0`, great! -- Now I am at the point where I am able to receive the packets even on the guest VMs. Only problem is: It only works if I flush the firewall rules given by `libvirtd`. But then the outbound traffic from the guest VM goes back via `ens1`, while inbound I get on `ens3` (= persistent network with the public subnet).

Comment: Seems the firewall issue was an easy fix, I added `<forward mode='route'/>`. But the outbound traffic from the VM guest is still sent back from `ens1` instead of `ens3`.

Comment: I can't really help much with libvirt configuration, but as for directing the outbound reply traffic, that's where policy-routing rules come in, approximately like in point 7. (Mainly on the VM host; the asymmetric routing on your VM might be "fine"... And I think it should be enough to have just one interface on the VM handling all traffic, with all routing logic being only on the host. But if you specifically want the VM to have two interfaces, then the VM may also need its own policy-routing rules.)

Comment: Seems that step by step I am coming closer to what I wanted. You are fabulous. How can I thank you, are you open to donations? :)